# Write a public method firstFifteen() that returns a String consisting of the first fifteen characters in the longNumber

Tags: java, string

I am starting to learn Java and the content in which we learn from I just CANNOT get on with, it doesn't explain much but just gives you a mild example and tells you to do it yourself with something completely different. as above I need to take the 'longNumber' string and take the last character off it.

````
 * Write a description of class CreditCardChecker here.
 * 
 * @author Craig Beverley 
 * @version 03/12/2020
 */
public class CreditCardChecker
{
   // Variable for long numbers to be checked
   public String longNumber;
   public StringBuilder firstFifteen;
 

   /**
    * Constructor for objects of class CreditCardChecker
    * including long number and first fifteen
    */
   public CreditCardChecker(String longNumber)
   {
      // initialise long number variable
      this.longNumber=longNumber;
   }
   /**
    * Sets the value of long number
    */
   public void setLongNumber(String aLongNumber)
   {
      this.longNumber=aLongNumber;
   }

   /**
    * method to get the long number
    */
   public String getLongNumber()
   {
      return this.longNumber;
   } 
  /**
   * method to check that long number has exactly 16 digits
   */    
  public boolean isCorrectLength()
  {
     if (longNumber.length() == 16)
     {
        return (true);
      }
      else
      {
         return (false);
      }
   }
   /**
    * Method to get the first 15 characters of long number
    */
   public String firstFifteen(String longNumber)
   {
    firstFifteen=longNumber.deleteCharAt(16);
   }
}```
````

Comment: Question says last charater of  a string. Title says first 15 characters. Which is it?

Comment: sorry. i need to delete the last character of a 16 digit string to retain the first 15 characters

Comment: Are you sure you want to "delete"? You could [use `setLength` or `subString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead

Comment: Also, the method comment seems to suggest simply getting the value and returning it, not actually removing anything from the StringBuilder.

Comment: i will also need that same last character at a later point in the code yes, so I guess it would be the subString option?

Comment: 1) You already are using `StringBuilder firstFifteen`. 2) If you did delete the character or modify that field, then you wouldn't be able to access that character at a later point

Comment: the compiler states that it cannot find symbol deleteCharAt() though, so I am not sure how i would go about writing it the way that i need it

Comment: Dont know what version of Java you are using, but, again, if you are going to be checking credit card numbers, you don't want to actually delete any characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure you need `firstFifteen` as a field. You can simply grab the first 15 characters

```
return longNumber.substring(0, 15);
```

You also don't need a parameter for that method, since `longNumber` is a field

Comment: This is brilliant thank you, that is the first i have heard the term field and parameter, presuming it is just different terminology... 

was the field thefirstFifteen= ?

and 

firstFifteen(String longNumber) the argument the parameter?

Comment: `public StringBuilder firstFifteen;` is a field of the class. The arguments to methods are otherwise known as parameters